# Accesing the USART registers by Arduino

Tags: serial, library

I'm having a hard time understanding how the Arduino libraries are defining the address for accessing the registers of the USART modules.

I cant find definition for `udr(pointer)` as used in the delegated constructor for Hardware Serial. So how does the class gets the underlying address? And what type of declaration is this?

```
HardwareSerial::HardwareSerial(
  volatile uint8_t *ubrrh, volatile uint8_t *ubrrl,
  volatile uint8_t *ucsra, volatile uint8_t *ucsrb,
  volatile uint8_t *ucsrc, volatile uint8_t *udr) :
    _ubrrh(ubrrh), _ubrrl(ubrrl),
    _ucsra(ucsra), _ucsrb(ucsrb), _ucsrc(ucsrc),
    _udr(udr),
    _rx_buffer_head(0), _rx_buffer_tail(0),
    _tx_buffer_head(0), _tx_buffer_tail(0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is handed the addresses when the object is constrcted:

```
 HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR);
```

`&UDR` is passed as `*udr`. That is then assigned to `_udr` in the initialiser list.